# Keyboard language not consistent

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Since my upgrade from 16.04 (where everything worked as expected), I have some trouble especially within JetBrains IDEs.
My laptop has a German keyboard which I switched to English UK. Using normal keys works fine (Y is on the Z key and vice versa) but combined with the CTRL key, they are swapped again (pressing CTRL+Z executes "Back" action, CTRL-Y deletes a line, etc). Why are the keys swapped back in combination with a modifier.

Comment: You are probably facing a common problem in UI programming: how to handle shortcuts: by key symbol or by key code. The former means "whatever key produces a `Z`(or `z`) symbol, if it is pressed and CTRL is held, undo the last operation". The latter means " if CTRL and the key that produces a `Z` on an english keyboard are pressed simultaneously, undo the last operation." The real problem here is that both arguments are valid: "I want [CTRL]+[Z] to work wherever the Z may be on my keyboard (by key symbol)" and "I want [CTRL]+[the Z key on my keyboard] to work regardless of the keyboard layout".